# zsh apt-get autocomplete doesn't work with fake root

Tags: command-line, apt, zsh, auto-completion

We're using fake root environment at work. Basically it is a bunch of directories which emulate `apt-get` and `dpkg` if some environment variables are set. I.e. you run `apt-get install xxx` and package `xxx` is being installed into this environment but not into the system.

When I used bash, apt-get autocomplete worked perfectly. When I typed `apt-get install <Tab><Tab>`, it showed me the list of local packages if I was in a fake root and the global list otherwise.

However, when I switched to zsh weird things happened. Currently only global packages show up in the list, though it was not always the case. Here is the complete story.

1. I install Ubuntu and setup the fake root and zsh.
2. I reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, saving `/home` which was on a separate partition.
3. Now zsh autocomplete *always* show me the packages from the fake root, regardless whether I have the env vars set.
4. I reinstall zsh and zsh-common. Now completion *always* work as no fake root exist. At the same moment I realize that after reinstall the folder `Ubuntu` disappeared from `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion`, now apt-get completion rules are taken from `Debian` folder.

Could you please explain me what could happen here and how can I setup zsh completion work with both system and fake apt-get?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2.

P.S. My fake root is not related to `fakeroot` command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have finally figured it out. Zsh completion engine caches several things, including the list of available packages returned by apt. Now my story seems clear: when autocomplete always suggested me packages from the fake root it was because first time I ran zsh in the fake root environment and the corresponding package list got into a cache.

If you want to override it (assuming you use oh-my-zsh) just add the following code into your .zshrc before calling oh-my-zsh:

```
if [[ check for fakeroot ]]; then
  export ZSH_CACHE_DIR=desired-cache-dir-name
fi
```

This separates completion caching between fake root and the base system and solves the problem from the post.